Amplify deployment error with no error after build
I've been going crazy for several days now. I have a project with vue3 that is deployed to amplify from bitbucket. There is no pipeline or anything, just the amplify.yml which I don't even have in the project.
The thing is that it gets to the build, tells me that build is ok and then the deployment fails without any further information. There is no error in the log or anything...
By putting an exit to the build I do see that something is failing, but I can't think of what the hell it could be.
2024-08-19T00:18:42.674Z [INFO]: ✓ built in 3.48s
2024-08-19T00:18:42.702Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-08-19T00:18:42.702Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1
2024-08-19T00:18:42.702Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.703Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.776Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2024-08-19T00:18:42.777Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed

Here full build log:
2024-08-19T00:16:15.474Z [INFO]: Git SSH Key acquired
2024-08-19T00:16:15.555Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: XXXXXXXXXXX
2024-08-19T00:16:23.229Z [INFO]: Agent pid 434
2024-08-19T00:16:23.304Z [INFO]: Identity added: /root/.ssh/git_rsa (/root/.ssh/git_rsa)
                                 Cloning into 'front'...
2024-08-19T00:16:23.304Z [INFO]: # Switching to commit: 8ccc6442d485e80fd160a7ad5410b080e48a9e5a
2024-08-19T00:16:23.333Z [INFO]: Agent pid 445
2024-08-19T00:16:23.334Z [INFO]: Identity added: /root/.ssh/git_rsa (/root/.ssh/git_rsa)
                                 Note: switching to '8ccc6442d485e80fd160a7ad5410b080e48a9e5a'.
                                 You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
                                 changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
                                 state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
                                 If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
                                 do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
                                 git switch -c <new-branch-name>
                                 Or undo this operation with:
                                 git switch -
                                 Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
                                 HEAD is now at 8ccc644 import change
2024-08-19T00:16:23.347Z [INFO]: Successfully cleaned up Git credentials
2024-08-19T00:16:23.347Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src220936981/src/front/.gitmodules
2024-08-19T00:16:23.354Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2024-08-19T00:16:23.426Z [INFO]: # Retrieved environment cache
2024-08-19T00:16:23.427Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2024-08-19T00:16:23.427Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d4p9r0oy1ofq1/develop/","WithDecryption":true}
2024-08-19T00:16:23.475Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
2024-08-19T00:16:27.176Z [INFO]: # Node version 20.16.0 is available for installation
2024-08-19T00:16:27.253Z [INFO]: # Installing Node version 20.16.0
2024-08-19T00:17:47.421Z [INFO]: # Now using Node version 20.16.0
2024-08-19T00:17:47.549Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2024-08-19T00:17:47.579Z [INFO]: # Retrieved cache
2024-08-19T00:17:50.935Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                                 ## Completed Backend Build
2024-08-19T00:17:50.945Z [INFO]: {"backendDuration": 0}
                                 ## Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: rm -rf node_modules
                                 # Executing command: rm -f package-lock.json
2024-08-19T00:17:50.946Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm install
2024-08-19T00:18:07.998Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
2024-08-19T00:18:08.132Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
2024-08-19T00:18:08.196Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
2024-08-19T00:18:08.197Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
2024-08-19T00:18:08.714Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated are-we-there-yet@2.0.0: This package is no longer supported.
2024-08-19T00:18:08.927Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated gauge@3.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
2024-08-19T00:18:09.288Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated npmlog@5.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
2024-08-19T00:18:13.389Z [INFO]: added 503 packages, and audited 504 packages in 22s
2024-08-19T00:18:13.395Z [INFO]: 110 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
                                 found 0 vulnerabilities
2024-08-19T00:18:13.415Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci
2024-08-19T00:18:15.938Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
2024-08-19T00:18:15.958Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated npmlog@5.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
2024-08-19T00:18:16.035Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
2024-08-19T00:18:16.079Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated are-we-there-yet@2.0.0: This package is no longer supported.
2024-08-19T00:18:16.099Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
2024-08-19T00:18:16.100Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
2024-08-19T00:18:16.216Z [WARNING]: npm warn deprecated gauge@3.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
2024-08-19T00:18:19.433Z [INFO]: added 504 packages, and audited 505 packages in 6s
2024-08-19T00:18:19.442Z [INFO]: 110 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
                                 found 0 vulnerabilities
2024-08-19T00:18:19.454Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2024-08-19T00:18:19.454Z [INFO]: # Executing command: echo "VITE_API_URL=$API_URL" >> .env
                                 # Executing command: npm run build --debug || echo "Error en el build" && exit 1
2024-08-19T00:18:19.574Z [INFO]: > baiyby@0.0.0 build
                                 > npm run coverage && vite build
2024-08-19T00:18:19.698Z [INFO]: > baiyby@0.0.0 coverage
                                 > vitest run --coverage
2024-08-19T00:18:20.466Z [INFO]: 
2024-08-19T00:18:20.466Z [INFO]: RUN  v2.0.5 /codebuild/output/src220936981/src/front
                                 Coverage enabled with v8
2024-08-19T00:18:22.045Z [WARNING]: stderr | src/test/pages/ExerciseInfo.spec.ts > ExerciseInfo.vue Page > should load data correctly when the page is mounted
                                    [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function:  Promise { <pending> }
                                    at <Anonymous ref_for=true id=12 title="Sample Title"  ... >
                                    at <ExerciseInfo ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
                                    at <VTUROOT>
                                    [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function:  Promise { <pending> }
                                    at <Anonymous ref_for=true id=12 title="Sample Title"  ... >
                                    at <ExerciseInfo ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
                                    at <VTUROOT>
2024-08-19T00:18:22.045Z [WARNING]: stderr | src/test/pages/ExerciseInfo.spec.ts > ExerciseInfo.vue Page > should display the Loading component when loading is true
                                    [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function:  Promise { <pending> }
                                    at <Anonymous ref_for=true id=12 title="Sample Title"  ... >
                                    at <ExerciseInfo ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
                                    at <VTUROOT>
                                    stderr | src/test/pages/ExerciseInfo.spec.ts > ExerciseInfo.vue Page > should toggle the menu when toggleMenu is called
                                    [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function:  Promise { <pending> }
                                    at <Anonymous ref_for=true id=12 title="Sample Title"  ... >
                                    at <ExerciseInfo ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
                                    at <VTUROOT>
2024-08-19T00:18:22.047Z [INFO]: ✓ src/test/pages/Portfolio.spec.ts  (6 tests) 159ms
........... ALL TEST ARE OK
2024-08-19T00:18:38.533Z [INFO]: 
2024-08-19T00:18:38.535Z [INFO]: Test Files  38 passed (38)
2024-08-19T00:18:38.535Z [INFO]: Tests  156 passed (156)
2024-08-19T00:18:38.539Z [INFO]: Start at  00:18:20
2024-08-19T00:18:38.539Z [INFO]: Duration  18.07s (transform 4.55s, setup 4.12s, collect 5.58s, tests 3.40s, environment 22.89s, prepare 4.00s)
2024-08-19T00:18:38.540Z [INFO]: % Coverage report from v8
2024-08-19T00:18:38.549Z [INFO]: -------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
2024-08-19T00:18:38.549Z [INFO]: File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
                                 -------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
2024-08-19T00:18:38.550Z [INFO]: All files          |   57.65 |    76.07 |      43 |   57.65 |
                                 -------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
........... REMOVED COVERAGE FROM LOG BECAUSE STACK OVERFLOW CHAR LIMIT
2024-08-19T00:18:39.171Z [INFO]: vite v5.4.1 building for production...
2024-08-19T00:18:39.229Z [INFO]: transforming...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.138Z [INFO]: ✓ 308 modules transformed.
2024-08-19T00:18:42.382Z [INFO]: rendering chunks...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.638Z [INFO]: computing gzip size...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.672Z [INFO]: dist/index.html                                             0.64 kB │ gzip:  0.39 kB
2024-08-19T00:18:42.672Z [INFO]: dist/assets/fa-v4compatibility-BX8XWJtE.woff2               4.80 kB
........... HERE ALL DIST BUILD                     
2024-08-19T00:18:42.674Z [INFO]: ✓ built in 3.48s
2024-08-19T00:18:42.702Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-08-19T00:18:42.702Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1
2024-08-19T00:18:42.702Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.703Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2024-08-19T00:18:42.776Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2024-08-19T00:18:42.777Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed

This is my amplify.yml file
To see the exit the build was like this:
- npm run build || echo "Error en el build" && exit 1

Now the file is this:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - rm -rf node_modules
        - rm -f package-lock.json
        - npm install
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo "VITE_API_URL=$API_URL" >> .env 
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*

I have the environment variable set to override the enviroment file, so I don't have to commit it.
When I run local buildea it works fine, it starts the vite fine and even doing an npx serve -s dist loads the web fine with its redirects etc.
The main branch works fine for me, but there have been a lot of changes made to it. There are some files that make me suspicious, but I can't see them. They only attract my attention because they touch the API variable.
/src/types/custom.d.ts
/**
 * Module declaration for importing SVG files as URLs.
 * This allows you to import SVGs with the '?url' suffix,
 * treating them as strings (URL paths).
 */
declare module "*.svg?url" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

/**
 * Module declaration for importing SVG files as raw content or components.
 * This allows you to import SVGs directly, treating them as strings or Vue components.
 */
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}

declare module "*.jpg" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}

/**
 * Interface for environment variables.
 * Includes only variables prefixed with VITE_ and are accessible in the client-side code.
 */
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly VITE_API_URL: string;
}

/**
 * Extension of the ImportMeta interface to include environment variables.
 */
interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv;
}

declare module "flush-promises" {
  const flushPromises: () => Promise<void>;
  export default flushPromises;
}

/src/services/axiosInstance.ts
import axios from 'axios';

/**
 * Creates an Axios instance with base configuration for API requests.
 * Includes request and response interceptors for handling authentication and errors.
 */
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL, // Base URL from Vite environment variables
  timeout: 10000, // 10-second timeout for requests
});

/**
 * Request interceptor to add the authentication token to the headers if available.
 * @param config - Axios request configuration object.
 * @returns The modified config with the Authorization header if the token is present.
 */
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('userSession');
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
);

/**
 * Response interceptor to handle global errors.
 * @param response - Axios response object.
 * @returns The response if successful, or rejects with an error.
 */
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;

I have checked the Key sensitive a thousand times and compared branches and still nothing. I have run EsLint to check the imports and still nothing.
I leave here the config of vite, ts and main in case they are useful too:
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import VueI18nPlugin from "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite";
import svgLoader from "vite-svg-loader";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/locales/**"),
    }),
    svgLoader(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: "./setupTests.js",
    transformMode: {
      web: [/\.[jt]sx$/],
    },
  },
  root: ".",
});

vite-env.d.ts
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

    declare module "*.vue" {
      import type { DefineComponent } from "vue";
    
      const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
      export default component;
    }

**tsconfig.json**

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "types": ["vitest/globals","vitest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": ".", 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

/src/main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import router from "./router";
import i18n from './i18n';
import App from "./App.vue";

import "./styles/style.css";
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
});

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  mutations: {
    setLoading(state, value) {
      state.isLoading = value;
    },
  },
});

const globalData = {
  $sessionData: [],
  $axios: { ...axiosInstance },
  updateSessionData(newData) {
    this.$sessionData = newData;
  },
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  store.commit('setLoading', true);
  return config;
}, (error) => {
  store.commit('setLoading', false);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  store.commit('setLoading', false);
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  store.commit('setLoading', false);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.provide('globalData', globalData);
app.config.globalProperties.$globalData = globalData;

app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.use(i18n);

app.mount("#app");

export { globalData };




can you send me you build log @GDP

and also your override settings of enviromental varaibles , after redactingt the values

@nabinsademba added build log at start of question, what do you mean with override settings of enviromental varaibles?

i can clearly see where the error is 2024-08-19T00:16:23.475Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets  you just neet paste the enviromental varaibles that you have setup in amplify. redact the varaibles value and send me image link. i think then i can resolve yoru issue

@nabinsademba i havent any secret configured. On the other branch its the same warning and it compiled properly.

you dont have any envirometnal varaibles setup at all for this project in amplify?? then its really weird application not building becasue sometimes they create override for the env variables for one branch and forget to create for another branch , which will result in failuer if you push to the branch for which the env var is not setup.

as you said this I have the environment variable set to override the enviroment file, so I don't have to commit it i was asking to see the env varaible setup and the build fail is also point towards it

@nabinsademba no no, of course, i have enviroment variables configured on amplify, but no secrets. Added screen captures at end of question. I just let only one for all branches thinking it was the problem. This API_URL is saved on the new .env file using echo "VITE_API_URL=$API_URL" >> .env on amplify.yml. And VITE_API_URL used on my app. I try to write it by hand and without variable and its the same problem, so i discard this casuistry.

should i write the solution here or should i answer it?? i think i got your issue

What you want, :P

@nabinsademba put here, if its ok put it in a comment and i vote and give it as OK

@nabinsademba do you need package.json?

i have edited your amplify build settings, this is what i use for my micro frontends:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm cache clean --force
        - npm install
        - npm ci
        - echo "VITE_API_URL=$API_URL" >> .env
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*


Same, getting error after building successfully.
Setting exit error un npm receiving same codes
2024-08-20T11:27:00.079Z [INFO]: ✓ built in 3.40s
2024-08-20T11:27:00.107Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-08-20T11:27:00.107Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1
2024-08-20T11:27:00.108Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-08-20T11:27:00.108Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2024-08-20T11:27:00.173Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2024-08-20T11:27:00.173Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed

add me as IAM user with amplify permisson to your aws i will resolve it for you

Hi, I don't know how to do the user thing. On the other hand, I think it's something from amplify for sure, because I have deployed a new application in which the main branch is dev and it works without problem and when I put a secondary branch, this time main, it fails. Therefore, the secondary branches always fail.

i have been deploying microfrontends for 100 plus hospitals each having dev, uat and prod branch i am not sure why its failing for you. i could help you if you could give me acess  thats all i can say. its very unlikely working in once branch and not working on others but its possible too considering the aws services available in different region
